# httpd cant serve index from new folder created under /var/www/html/gci

Tags: docker, apache, webserver, microservices

I have created a new folder and copy my index html from that image. The image looks like this

```
 FROM centos:latest
 RUN yum update -y
 RUN yum install httpd -y
 RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/gci/
 COPY ./public-html/ /var/www/html/gci/
 ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

However this defaults to serving from /var/www/html/ and not from /var/www/html/gci
Without this new folder, it works just fine serving index.html file I have in public-html folder.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

oh it works, just needed to add /gci when searching in the browser and Kaboom works like magic

Answer (score 0):

You should edit Apache2 conf to serve directly from /cgi

First, create a cgi.conf file (or whatever name you want), with those values **at minimum** *(it would be better to delve a bit more on apache2 conf than just this) *

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add this file in your image `ADD cgi.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available`

Then deactivate the default site and activate yours `RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf && a2ensite cgi.conf`

After that, when launching your containerand trying to access it, you'll directlygo to the /cgi directory.